# How to exclude people when posting in Google+

Tags: google-plus

I want to share my post in Google+ with everyone except a specific user. Is it possible in Google+? (If it matters, this user in one of my circles.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way currently is to create another circle with all the people you **do** want to share it with and to not include the person you **don't** want to share it with. You can then share it with this new circle and make sure you lock the post, so it doesn't get re-shared.

This is a frequently requested feature, so you should also *Send feedback* to Google to voice your opinion that this should be added.